# InvalidClassException exception during deserilization

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Getting InvalidClassException during de-serializing object from session. User data we store in database and in the next request to server it is loaded from table to do few checks. Original value serialVersionUID is defined in the class as 1L and there is no change in this class from long time. Not sure how this new serialVersionUID value 79642633333 coming while deserializing object and this error coming in the few clusters/server not everywhere.

I have checked there are no duplicate jar versions or duplicate class present anywhere in the classpath.

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.test.User; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = 79642633333

Value defined in the class:
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Comment: Remove the default serialVersionUID and generate one.

Answer (score 0):

During **deserialization**, receiver side JVM will compare the unique ID associated with the Object with local class Unique ID i.e. JVM will also create a Unique ID based on the corresponding .class file which is present in the receiver system. If both unique ID matched then only **deserialization** will be performed. Otherwise we will get `InvalidClassException`. This unique Identifier is nothing but SerialVersionUID.

So basically SerialVersionUID during serialization should match with SerialVersionUID deserialization.

Comment: `InvalidClassException` is not a `RuntimeException`. The OP claims, probably incorrectly, that he has already done all this.

Comment: Your reference is worthless, as it repeats the error about `RuntimeException`, nd it also makes the totally incorrect claim that the sender and receiver must have the same .class file. The whole point of `serialVersionUID` is that this does *not* have to be the case. It also uses the .txt extension for a file containing serialized data, which is not text. Find better resources, please.